# Remove contributors stats on specific files

Tags: git, github, gitattributes

I have a python that leverages html files and presents them. The html files are not really repository code and I don't want them included in the stats.

```
|package
|-- __init__.py
|-- code.py
|-- html_files
   |-- a.html
   |-- b.html
```

I want to exclude the folder `html_files` from github contributors stats.
It was easy to remove them from language stats with `.gitattributes` and `linguist` markup.
Is there something similar for contribution stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to exclude files from contribution stats.  GitHub looks only at commits to determine the contribution stats and doesn't inspect the files within them, since doing so would be very expensive.

In general, it's wise not to pay too much attention to contribution stats; they aren't really a good metric for measuring things and are intended as a rough overview.